# R 3d array to 2d matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

Let's assume I have a 3d array of dimensions (x,y,z) and would like to restructure my data as a matrix of dimensions (x*y,z), something like:

```
my_array <- array(1:600, dim=c(10,5,12))
my_matrix<-data.frame()

for (j in 1:5) {
  for (i in 1:10) {
     my_matrix <- rbind (my_matrix, my_array[i,j,1:12])
 }
}
```

Could you suggest a faster and more elegant way?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can convert to a `matrix` by calling the `matrix` and specifying the dimensions

```
res <- matrix(my_array, prod(dim(my_array)[1:2]), dim(my_array)[3])
all.equal(as.matrix(my_matrix), res, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

NOTE: This will not change the original 'my_array`.  Also, in fact, the code can be simplified to

```
matrix(my_array, 10*5, 12)
```

and make it compact.

```
nchar("matrix(my_array, 10*5, 12)")
#[1] 26

nchar("dim(my_array) <- c(10 * 5 , 12)")
#[1] 31
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, could you please add some words illustrating the second line of your code (all.equal(...))? thanks

Comment: @Nemesi It is just to check whether the results of 'my_matrix' is equal to the one I got.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but one has to carefully consider R's reading order. In my case I had to apply an aperm() to get the array right, before reading it into 2d form

Answer (score 13):

Change the dimension of the array:

```
dim(my_array) <- c(10 * 5 , 12)
```

Comment: Hi Lars, will this maintain the order of the data? I mean all the z values of the first y column, then the second and so on...

Comment: I wish I could accept both the answers: this gets the job done in a nice way as well (I up-voted it tho)

Comment: Hi, Nemesi.  I tested the solution and it gave the same result as the
one you initially had.  Note that an array is a vector with a
dimensional attribute, which is the reason this simple solution works.

Comment: Simple and nice solution. It works for both directions: (i)from 2d array (dims NxK*K) to 3d array (dims NxKxK), dim(my_array) <- c(N, K, K); or (ii) from 3d to 2d, dim(my_array) <- c(N, K*K).

Answer (score 1):

Both @akrun and @Lars Arne Jordanger's solutions work and generate the same results.

The two solutions work by:

(1) concatenating the first rows of all matrices together and placing these rows in the top of the combined matrix; and then

(2) concatenating the second rows of all matrices together and placing these rows under the concatenation of the first rows, and so on.

The following example illustrates the idea very well:

```
> threeDimArray <- array( NA, dim=c(3,3,4) )
> dims <- dim( threeDimArray )
> 
> constants <- c(1, 10, 100)
> for( id in 1:length(constants) ){
   const <- constants[id]
   threeDimArray[id,,] <- matrix( (1:prod(dims[2:3]))*const, dims[2], dims[3] )
 }
> threeDimArray[1,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
> threeDimArray[2,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10   40   70  100
[2,]   20   50   80  110
[3,]   30   60   90  120
> threeDimArray[3,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  100  400  700 1000
[2,]  200  500  800 1100
[3,]  300  600  900 1200
> # solution 1:
> twoDimMat <- matrix(threeDimArray, prod(dims[1:2]), dims[3])
> twoDimMat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    4    7   10
 [2,]   10   40   70  100
 [3,]  100  400  700 1000
 [4,]    2    5    8   11
 [5,]   20   50   80  110
 [6,]  200  500  800 1100
 [7,]    3    6    9   12
 [8,]   30   60   90  120
 [9,]  300  600  900 1200
> 
> # solution 2: 
> threeDArray <- threeDimArray
> dim(threeDArray) <- c(prod( dims[1:2] ), dims[3])
> threeDArray
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    4    7   10
 [2,]   10   40   70  100
 [3,]  100  400  700 1000
 [4,]    2    5    8   11
 [5,]   20   50   80  110
 [6,]  200  500  800 1100
 [7,]    3    6    9   12
 [8,]   30   60   90  120
 [9,]  300  600  900 1200
>
```